# WPF Static Resource

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to bind a string in the Window resources to a property.
I know that that binding works on dependency properties.
Does the string class in WPF have a dependency property?

Thank you

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="strWindow"> Content= myProperty </sys:String>
 </Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What is this resource used for? If it is used for another control(s), why don't you do the binding at the control(s)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You are right I can bind to at the control. Just exploring and testing things in wpf as I'm learning it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are exploring, then all I can say is that no one does it this way.

As for your question, `string` class does not dependency property of any kind. Only subclasses of `DependencyObject` class can have `DependencyProperty`. All WPF controls are subclasses of `DependencyObject`, and most of the properties we commonly access are coded as dependency property.

For example, `TextBox` is a subclass of `DependencyObject`, and has a `Text` property coded as a dependency property.

Do note that you can also build your own custom controls (by subclassing from `FrameworkElement` or one of its subclass), and write your own properties. If you don't code the property as a dependency property, that property will not be bindable.